# Error on razor page when searching for a string

Tags: asp.net-core, web, razor-pages

While learning about razor page in asp .net core, I encountered a bug, this section is added to search the string on the web page but the result does not change anything.
What should I do?
Please help me

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies
{

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext _context;

    public IndexModel(RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Movie> Movie { get;set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public SelectList Genre { get; set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string MovieGenre { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                     select m;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchString));
        }
        Movie = await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
    }

    
    
}
}
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvYe.png)

The result I expect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kff3c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I guess you may not set the right route for your route page and some logic is wrong in your OnGetAsync method.

Firstly, if you want to bind the SearchString as friendly url in the your path, I suggest you could set it as below in your razor page. Like below

```
@page "{SearchString}"
```

Then you could use `https://localhost:xxxx/Movies/Ghost` to access the page and it will bind the Ghost to SearchString automatcally.

Besides, I found you have re-query the Movie after the if condition. This will make the search result is not according to SearchString.

Like below:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchString));
        Movie = await movies.ToListAsync()
    }else{
       Movie = await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
    }

}
```

More details, you could refer to below test demo.

Razor page:

Since I don't know your movie razor page make up, I created a simple one.

```
@page "{SearchString}"
@model RazorPageRelated.MoviesModel
@{
}



<div class="text-center">
 
    @foreach (var item in Model.Movie)
    {
        <p>@item.Name</p><br/>
    }

</div>
```

Model Codes:

```
public class MoviesModel : PageModel
{

    public List<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

    public IList<Movie> Context = new List<Movie>() {
          new Movie{ Id=1, Name="When Harry"},
          new Movie{ Id=1, Name="Ghost22222"},
          new Movie{ Id=1, Name="Ghost11111"},
        };


    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            Movie = Context.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchString)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            Movie = Context.ToList();
        }
      
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `OnGetAsymc` method with below code

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 where string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString) || m.Title.Contains(SearchString)
                 select m;
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    //{
    //    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchString));
    //}
    Movie = movies.ToListAsync();//await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
}
```